# Displaying Photos on iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, three20

I'm working on an iPhone app and I need to be able to display images to users.  I have already gotten the code that takes the photo and stores it into the filesystem working well.  Now I just need to figure out how to display the image.

I've looked at the Three20 project I've read about on a few of the posts here, but it seems a bit cumbersome and like an extra dependency to import link and combine all of the Three20 library into my little app.

Are there any other ways or a more streamlined library that will let me display photos to my users?

Thanks!
B.

Answer (score 1):

Throw a `UIImageView` on the screen? Or ask a more specific question if that is not what you want.